# iScroll5 & Jquery mobile table horizontal scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, iscroll

I'm trying to implement a horizontal scroll on a jquery mobile table using iScroll 5 http://iscrolljs.com/ however it's not working at all. The vertical scoll works but it totally ignores the horizontal scroll. Here's my code:

```
<body onload="loaded()">

  <div data-role="page" id="scroll" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content">

    <div id="wrapper">

        <table data-role="table" id="table-column-toggle" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
             <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th data-priority="1">Rank</th>
                 <th data-priority="1">Movie Title </th>
                 <th data-priority="1">Year</th>
                 <th data-priority="1"><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Rating</abbr></th>
                 <th data-priority="1">Reviews</th>
                 <th data-priority="1">Rank</th>
                 <th data-priority="1">Movie Title </th>
                 <th data-priority="1">Year</th>
                 <th data-priority="1"><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Rating</abbr></th>
                 <th data-priority="1">Reviews</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <th>1</th>
                 <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td>
                 <td>1941</td>
                 <td>100%</td>
                 <td>74</td>
                 <th>1</th>
                 <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td>
                 <td>1941</td>
                 <td>100%</td>
                 <td>74</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <th>2</th>
                 <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_(film)" data-rel="external">Casablanca</a></td>
                 <td>1942</td>
                 <td>97%</td>
                 <td>64</td>
                 <th>1</th>
                 <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td>
                 <td>1941</td>
                 <td>100%</td>
                 <td>74</td>
               </tr>

             </tbody>
           </table>

    </div> <!-- end wrapper -->

</div><!-- /content -->
```

and the jquery:

```
<script >

  var myScroll;

  function loaded () {
   myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
    eventPassthrough: true, 
    scrollX: true, 
    scrollY: false, 
    mouseWheel: true, 
    preventDefault: false
    });

  }

</script>
```

Does anyone have any idea's on this one? If I remove the table and put in a list it scrolls horizontally as I would expect. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7uAhg/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way of achieving this without using iScroll 5. Wrap the table in the following div: `<div style="overflow:auto; width: 100%; ">`. This will enable scrolling but then the toggle column button scrolls along with the table. See this answer for the full working code and js fiddle

[jquery mobile issue with data-column-btn positioning when allowing horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393102/jquery-mobile-issue-with-data-column-btn-positioning-when-allowing-horizontal-sc)